# Can I see if someone is using browser snapshot on my website?

Tags: browsers

Can I see if someone uses snapshots to store parts of my website as images in their laptop, using browser snapshot tool?

Comment: As opposed to with any other screenshot tool?  Why the focus on Firefox snapshots?

Comment: Ok, I corrected it...!! So, can someone identify if there is use of that kind of tools?

Comment: I usually use a screenshot tool that doesn't run in the browser at all.  I like the ones where I can draw a box on the screen and it creates an image from that.

Comment: Why would you care?

Comment: Any images that your web site displays will be available in the browser cache, where the user can retrieve them.

Comment: Android applications can set a "do not allow screenshots" flag, mostly seen in banking apps. I personally find that annoying and there are ways around it, but writing a thin app wrapper with this flag might be enough to fulfill your requeriment.

Comment: are you also asking if you would know if someone took a picture of their screen?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

No, as there is no API for detecting screenshots. It's impossible to arbitrarily know what happens outside the browser as that would be a security issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can track the clicks on the keys like PrtSc with JS

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Wouldn't this particular key be handled by the operating system, so the browser was not even informed of it?